# Angular 11 HTML tag <script> equivalent

Tags: javascript, html, angular, templates

In asp.net, I used to use this code

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.europetnet.org/epn-badge.js?IDC,grey"></script>
</div>
```

to display a badge from external source.

This url contains following code:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName ('script');
for (var s, i = scripts.length; i && (s = scripts[--i]);) {
    if ((s = s.getAttribute ('src')) && (s = s.match (/^(.*)epn-badge.js(\?\s*(.+))?\s*/))) {
        break;
    } 
}

var word = s[3];
var isStyle = (word.indexOf(',') >= 0) ? true : false;
if( isStyle ) {
    var word = word.split(',');
    
    /* jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://www.europetnet.org/update_badge.php',
        data: {badge: word[0]},
        success: function (data) {
            
        },
        error: function () {
        
        }
    }); */  
    
    var word = word[0]+'&style='+word[1];
}

document.write('<style type="text/css">');
document.write('#epnbadgeiframewrapper {');
    document.write('height: auto;');
document.write('}');

document.write('#epnbadgeiframe {');
    document.write('border: medium none;');
    document.write('width: 205px;');
    document.write('height: 35px;');
document.write('}');
document.write('</style>');

document.write('<div id="epnbadgeiframewrapper"><iframe id="epnbadgeiframe" src="//www.europetnet.org/epn-badge/epn-badge.php?id='+word+'"></iframe></div>');
```

I try to do the same in Angular 11, but script tag is not allowed.

I tried this code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.script = this.renderer2.createElement("script");
    this.script.type = "text/javascript";
    this.script.src = "https://www.europetnet.org/epn-badge.js?IDC,grey";
    this.script.text = ``;
    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.document.body, this.script);
```

I do not see how to use it in html template.

Comment: if you are talking to include a permanent application external library, you could include the <script> tag in your angular index.html file (as a last element in the body tag)

Comment: In my old application, the badge was displayed this way. See vet.idchips.com, the Europenet badge on the left

Comment: first: you did not specified the **ngOnInit** you used in wich component ? i suppose it is in **app.component** , Second you did not specify if your script is dynamic (changeable) or static (unchangeable) , finally: i suggest to use **document.createElement(..)** instead of rendrer, and see if this will work